# On what day did Jesus die?

Tags: life-of-jesus, crucifixion, death, resurrection-of-jesus, easter

If Easter Sunday (First day of the week) is the day Jesus rose the dead, why is Good Friday the day we recognize as the day Jesus died? That wouldn't give 3 days and 3 nights in the grave like Jesus prophesied.

> For as Jonas was three days and three nights in the whale's belly; so shall the Son of man be three days and three nights in the heart of the earth. (Matthew 12:40)

Comment: Welcome! This question (or one very similar to it) has already been asked, so this one may be closed as a duplicate. I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: @Nathaniel - yeah, i suppose so. it's [very] slightly different, but i can close it. the other one didn't come up in my search, which is why i asked it. thanks.

Comment: Yes, I can understand that—to me this is a very good duplicate to keep around as a sign post.